# Xcode error with seemingly no working solution/fix (The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time)

Tags: swift, xcode

Context: i'm taking a programming class while i try to move schools so i can study my true passion in media. sorry for my sloppy programming/lack of knowledge.

My current assessment piece is to create a visual weather app which i've nearly completed. My only issue is that at line 15 (where my body view is) creates an error that reads "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

I've already tried breaking the expression up, but all attempts have created random errors.

i'm running Xcode version 12.4 on a 2017 Macbook air running macOS catalina 10.15.4.

the code in question is bellow, just with some formatting errors due to something (im not actually sure what)

'''

import SwiftUI

import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        //background
        if let icon = networkManager.weather?.current.icon.rawValue{
            Image(icon)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
        //foreground
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            .frame(height:350)
            
            VStack(spacing:0){
                //current Temperature
                HStack(alignment: .center){
                    if let currentIcon = networkManager.weather?.current.icon {
                        currentIcon.image
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }else {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.icloud")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                    }
                    if let currentTemp = networkManager.weather?.current.temperature {
                        Text("\(currentTemp, specifier: "%.1f")˚C")
                           .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 60))
                    } else {
                      Text("--.-")
                           .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 60))
                    }
                }.frame(height:60)
                //H/L
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("HIGH")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        HStack{
                            if let myDailyHigh = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.maxTemperature {
                                Text("\(myDailyHigh, specifier: "%.0f")")
                                    .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            } else {
                                Text("--.-˚")
                                    .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                            
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    VStack{
                        Text("LOW")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        HStack{
                            if let myDailyLow = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.minTemperature {
                                Text("\(myDailyLow, specifier: "%.0f")")
                                    .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            } else {
                                Text("--.-˚")
                                    .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                                    
                            }
                            

                            }
                        }
                    
                };.frame(height:40)
                if let summary = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.summary {
                    Text(summary)
                        .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        .padding()
                } else {
                    Text("Downloading weather data - please be patient, this is a slowass.")
                        .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            //random
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("HUMIDITY")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 12))
                        if let humidity = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.humidity {
                            Text("\(humidity*100, specifier: "%.0f")%")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        } else {
                            Text("--%")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    VStack{
                        Text("DEW POINT")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 12))
                        if let dewPoint = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.dewPoint {
                            Text("\(dewPoint, specifier: "%.0f")˚C")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        } else {
                            Text("--˚")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    VStack{
                        Text("PRESSURE")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 12))
                        if let pressure = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.pressure{
                            Text("\(pressure, specifier: "%.1f") hPa")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 17.5))
                        } else {
                            Text("--.- hPa")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 17.5))
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    VStack{
                        Text("WIND SPEED")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 12))
                        if let windSpeed = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.windSpeed {
                            Text("\(windSpeed, specifier: "%.1f") Km/h")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 17.5))
                        } else {
                            Text("-.- Km/h")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 17.5))
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    VStack{
                        Text("RAIN")
                            .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 12))
                        if let rain = networkManager.weather?.week.list.first!.precipProbability {
                            Text("\(rain, specifier: "%.0f")%")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        } else {
                            Text("--%")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 20))
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                .padding(.init(top: 10.0, leading: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, trailing: 10.0))
                .background(Color(.white).opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                Divider()
                //Weekly view at bot
                HStack{
                    ForEach (1..<8) {index in
                        VStack{
                            //
                            if let currentIcon = networkManager.weather?.week.list[index].icon {
                                currentIcon.image
                            }else {
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.icloud")
                            }
                            //

                            Text("\(weekday(from: Date(), index:index))")
                                .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 10))
                            HStack{
                                if let currentMax = networkManager.weather?.week.list[index].maxTemperature {
                                    Text("\(currentMax, specifier:"%.0f")˚")
                                        .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                } else {
                                    Text("--˚")
                                        .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 14))
                                }
                                if let currentMin = networkManager.weather?.week.list[index].minTemperature {
                                    Text("\(currentMin, specifier:"%.0f")˚")
                                        .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                } else {
                                    Text("--˚")
                                        .font(.custom("01 Digit", size: 14))
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }.frame(width:50)
                        .padding(.init(top: 10.0, leading: 1, bottom: 10.0, trailing: 1.0))
                        .background(Color(.white).opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .stroke(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height:120)
            }
            Spacer()
                .frame(hight:100)
            Image("DarkSky")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height:120)
    }
}
```

}
}
'''

Comment: Your View is way to complicated you should separate smaller views into their own views and remove all those if let else think of all that work being redone every time SwiftUI decided to reload the struct. If you start commenting out portions of your view you will find the cause. Sometimes it could be a typo or a particular nuance. Also switch ObservedObject to StateObject for stability

Comment: Although you have tried breaking it up already, it’s worth another shot — try to be as methodical as possible and start by including only one element when you start. That’s likely the only way you’ll debug this, since no one can try the code you posted since NetworkManager isn’t included.

Comment: I can post the github repo i have if you guys want. i'll try the seperate views thing now, will report back soon.